# General Method for Calculating Excluded Volume

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, interactions, molecules

In section 5.3 of Kardar's Statistical Physics of Particles, the van der Waals equation is given as:

$[P+\frac{u_0 \Omega}{2}(\frac{N}{V})^2][V-\frac{N\Omega}{2}]=Nk_BT$

The van der Waals parameters are identified as $a = \frac{u_0 \Omega}{2}$ and $b=\frac{\Omega}{2}$. Here, $\Omega$ is the volume excluded around each particle (to the centers of the other atoms). The parameter $b$ is interpreted as the effective excluded volume for low densities due to the fact that for low densities ($\Omega \ll V$) the contribution of coordinates to the partition function is:

$V(V-\Omega)(V-2\Omega)...(V-(N-1)\Omega) \approx (V-\frac{N\Omega}{2})^N$ (Equation 5.46)

which explains the factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ in $b$. However, the author goes on to say that:

> Of course, the above result is only approximate since the effects of
> excluded volume involving more than two particles are not correctly
> taken into account. The relatively simple form of Eq. (5.46) is only
> exact for spatial dimensions d = 1, and at infinity.

I have some questions:

1- What does the author exactly mean when he says the expression is exact for $d=1$ and at "infinity"? Does he mean infinite number of particles?

2- How to incorporate the effects of excluded volume involving more than two particles? As an example I would be glad if someone explained it for 3 particles.

3- Is there a general method or algorithm to find the excluded volume involving any number of particles for any dimension $d$? If so, I would like to see some sources explaining these methods.

Answer (score 0):

1. He means the spatial dimension.
   In $d=1$ if you consider a 3-particle hard-ball cluster (3 hard-ball particles each overlapping with the remaining 2) it can only happen by taking two overlapping particles and slapping the third one in the middle. The 3-particle overlap will be the same as the overlap between two initial particles so I believe it factors out.
   In $d \rightarrow \infty$ I would expect the 3-particle (and higher-order contributions) to vanish. If you keep the particle volume constant and increase the spatial dimension, the particle radius has to decrease. It becomes progressively less likely for 3-particles to meet each other at the same time. In both cases, this is only an idea, but it should be quite easy to show through a direct calculation.
2. and 3. The cluster expansion seems to be an answer (although I am not sure since I only briefly heard about it). It is defined for any intermolecular potential but it should be quite simple for hard-ball potential. I think it would boil to the inclusion-exclusion principle.